# Div with 2 spans, center 1, right align other, but keep first one centered

Tags: css, html

I have a div with 2 spans in it.  I want to keep the 1st span centered relative to the div and right align the 2nd (I'm using pull-right from bootstrap).

In the below JSBin, you'll see what I'm after.  I want the 'Hello' span in Div1 to be in the same position as it is in Div2.  In otherwords, I want to center the 1st span relative to the parent, and not be affected by any other spans in the div...

Here's my jsbin: http://jsbin.com/cixun/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to position the right `span` absolutely, relative to the `div`:

http://jsbin.com/wuged/1/edit

```
.row{
  position: relative;
}

.right{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```
<div class="row black center" >
   <span class="first">Hello</span>

   <span class="right">more text on the right</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to absolutely position the right-span, instead of floating it. That will take it out of the flow, and the other span wont' "feel" it, and be more correctly in the center of the page

**css**

```
.row{position:relative;} /*required to make this a positioning container for abs.     
            positioned span */
.right{position:absolute;right:0px;}
```